# nginx routing based on ip address

Tags: regex, nginx

I am wondering if it is possible to compute some kind of hash value from ip address or do modulo operation on the last numeric value from ip address (for example on 24 given 172.16.4.24)? Based on this, I want to send the request to different endpoints (not to different servers). If this can be done without installing any new module, that would be the best.

As far as I can see, I feel like I should do something similar using the regex?

Comment: You want to pass request to different `location`s?

Comment: I want to pass requests to different endpoints in my upstream web server

Comment: Do you need control on splitting? There is http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_split_clients_module.html